Analytically solving this second order ODE
I try to solve this second order differential equations to get $\phi$:
$$
4 \Psi \left( \ddot{\phi}_0+ \frac{a^2}{2\phi_0}\dot{\phi}_0 \right)   =  -\ddot{\phi}+ \left( \frac{a^2 \mathcal{H}}{2\phi_0} \mathcal{H} + \frac{a^2 \dot{\phi}_0}{\phi_0} \right) \dot{\phi}- \left( 3 k^2 - \frac{a^2 \ddot{\phi}_0}{\phi_0} -  \frac{\mathcal{H} a^2 \dot{\phi}_0}{\phi_0} - \frac{2 a \dot{a} \dot{\phi}_0}{\phi_0} + \frac{a^2 \dot{\phi}_0}{\phi_0^2}+ \frac{\mathcal{H} a^2}{\phi_0} -  \frac{a^4 \dot{\phi_0}}{4\phi^2_0}      \right) \phi ~~~~~~~~~~~~ (1) 
$$
Where $\Psi$ is defined from this ODE:
$$
\left( k^2 + 3 \mathcal{H}^2 +3 \mathcal{H}  \frac{a^2\dot{\phi}_0}{2\phi_0} \right) \Psi = - \frac{\ddot{\phi}}{2\phi_0} +
\dot{\phi} \left( \frac{\mathcal{H}}{2\phi_0} + \frac{\dot{\phi_0}}{2\phi_0}  - \frac{a^2 \mathcal{H}}{2\phi_0}  \right) +
\phi \left( \frac{\mathcal{H} \dot{\phi_0}}{\phi_0} + \frac{5\mathcal{H}a^2}{2\phi_0}-\frac{a^4 \dot{\phi}_0}{4\phi^2_0}    \right) ~~~~~~(2) 
$$
Both $\phi$ and $\Psi$ are functions of t. $\dot{\phi}=\frac{\partial}{\partial ~t} \phi$, and $\ddot{\phi}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2t} \phi$.
$a(t) = t + \frac{t^2}{2}, H(t) = \frac{\dot{a}}{a},~ \phi_0(t) =- \frac{e^{-Ht}}{H} $ and $k$ is a constant.
So when substituting by (2) into (1) and all the variables, I get a single second-order differential equation in $\phi$
Here is the code that I try:
a[t_]= t + t^2/2; h[t_]= Derivative[1][a][t]/a[t]; f0[t_]= -(Exp[-2*h[t]*t]/h[t]); df0[t_]= D[f0[t], t]; ddf0[t_]= D[f0[t], {t, 2}]; 
y[t_] := (1/(k^2 + 3*h[t] +  3*h[t]*((a[t]^2*df0[t])/(2*f0[t]))))*(-(Derivative[2][x][ t]/(2*f0[t])) +  (Derivative[1][x][t]/(2*f0[t]))*(h[t] + df0[t] -  a[t]^2*h[t]) +  (x[t]/(2*f0[t]))*(2*h[t]*df0[t] +  5*h[t]*a[t]^2 - (a[t]^4/(2*f0[t]))*df0[t]))
eq := Simplify[-Derivative[2][x][ t] + (Derivative[1][x][t]/f0[t])*((a[t]^2/2)*h[t] + h[t]*f0[t] +  a[t]^2*df0[t]) -  (x[t]/f0[t])*(3*k^2*f0[t] - a[t]^2*ddf0[t] -  h[t]*a[t]^2*df0[t] -  2*a[t]*Derivative[1][a][t]*df0[t] + (a[t]^2*df0[t])/f0[t] +  h[t]*a[t]^2 - (a[t]^4*df0[t])/(4*f0[t])) -  4*y[t]*(ddf0[t] + (a[t]^2/(2*f0[t]))*df0[t])]
Where $x(t)=\phi (t)$ , $y(t)=\Psi (t)$ and $f0(t) =\phi_0(t)$. Ofcourse DSolve doesn't work with eq. So I tried:
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eq == 0, x[0] == 0, Derivative[1][x][0] == 1},  x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
But it also doesn't give a solution. Hint: the initial conditions are arbitrary.
Another Hint: this equation can not be solved numerically because $k$ is an unknown constant.
So I appricticate any help in finding an analytic solution for this equation.

What is the parameter range of k ?

Would the quasi-static/subhorizon approximation work in your case? Getting the full analytical solution might be very difficult, that's why there are the Boltzmann codes out there ;-)

Why do you expect there to be an analytic solution to this equation?  Analytic solutions are rare, especially for nonlinear equations like yours. I'd be surprised if there was one here, unless you can find some conserved quantities or something to simplify the differential equation. Of course, that's a math problem rather than a Mathematica one.

@UlrichNeumann. $-5<k<5$.

@Dr.phy Your ode seems to be singulaer near t==0: {Coefficient[eq, x''[t]] /. t -> 0,   Asymptotic[eq /. x''[t] -> 0, t -> 0]} (*{-3, -((4 x[0])/(E^2 t)) + (3 Derivative[1][x][0])/t}*)

@UlrichNeumann. Can this equation be solved numerically with that range of $k$ parameter ?

@march. I try to find approximate or series expansion solutions.

@Dr.phy Numerical solution is possible if  you can eliminate the singularity I think

I'm not an expert in MA. So let me ask can this singularity be eliminated? I mean at the integral of NDSolve is there any command that eliminates singularities? Otherwise, the integral can be made from say  t=0.1 and also the IC can be evaluated at x[0.1]. So now is there a solution that could be found over a range of k? @UlrichNeumann

To eliminate the singlarity t==0(see my comment) try workaround
dt = .001;
X = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == 0, x[dt] == 0,Derivative[1][x][dt] == 1}, x, {t, dt, 10}, k ]

solution k=-5,-4,...,5
Plot[Table[X[k][t], {k, -5, 5}], {t, dt, 10}, PlotRange -> All]


Hope it helps!

fyi, you can just do dt = $MachineEpsilon; and it works also.

Thanks so much. Now I'm thinking can we get an analytic expression from this numeric solution? for instance by making fitting .. But can be this done with two variables $k$ and $t$? @UlrichNeumann

@Dr.phy You need an analytical formula? If not you can use X[k][t] like a build in function

I'm asking can we get an analytic formula from this numerical solution. @UlrichNeumann

@UlrichNeumann. Could you look at this thread pls? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/301410/find-fitting-for-a-multi-varibles-function
